# CSS Footer with responsive css

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a CSS Footer with this CSS:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#666666;
    clear:both;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.footer-container {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.social_links {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

.footer_text {
    text-align:center;
}

.footer_logo {
    float:right;
}
```

i want 3 columns, the left one fairly small just for facebook and twitter social icons displayed next to each other (inline) the middle column for text so that one larger and then the right one just for a small logo

i am trying to make it responsive too so as the page gets smaller, it goes in order:- the left column (social links) / middle column (text - aligned center) / the logo down the bottom

here is a fiddle with what i currently have but i cannot get it working as above.

http://jsfiddle.net/eYwsm/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the columns to be rows in mobile size this will do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/eYwsm/2/

.footer_text has `overflow: hidden` so it will take the remaining space between the floating elements.

Comment: thats what im looking for - however, is it possible to use responsive CSS to make the columns change into rows as the screen gets smaller?

Comment: I dont know any way of both having the width flexible between two floats without putting the element last.
I think you will have to put them in the order you want have them as rows and then float all three and set width on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a media query (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and have the elements display changed from inline to block at a certain width. For example, using this in your CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    .social_links, .footer_logo
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```